# Android GCM push notifications - sending messages to a set of devices

Tags: android, google-api, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have server which includes a database of usernames. I also have an Android app in which users will register themselves a username with the server database, and also register the device with the GCM part of the server.

I am currently using the GCM demo in my server code, and it will multicast a push notification to every registered device. However, I would like it so that push notifications are sent to certain users, not every registered GCM device.

My first idea was to associate each user in the database with their GCM regID. Will this work? I have read things about the regID changing or having duplicates, which makes it sound a somewhat unstable option for this purpose.

Any ideas on how I could achieve sending messages to certain devices would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I may not fully understand your main concern, but here are a few thoughts.

- You are correct, the GCM RegistrationID can be changed by Google and it is your apps responsibility to update the server with a new RegistrationID.
- You certainly should associate the user in the database with their respective GCM RegistrationID since the likelihood of a user having more than one device is high.
- There should be no issue with screaming through the database and sending a message per User  / per Device, but you will have to randomly pick the user/device combination if you only want to send a message only once to a user.

Again, not sure I understand your dilemma fully, but maybe this will help you think through possible solutions.